# Formatting for outlook html email, specifically removing border spacing in tables

Tags: html, email, outlook

Im guessing that outlook 07+ (the ones using MS Word for html) doesnt support the global CSS (*) and adding border-spacing 0 and padding 0 to the cells is not working, so what do I need to do to get rid of the cell padding and border-spacing?

Edit* border-collapse is not working either. Do I need to specifiy Doctype for html emails to get it to work?

Comment: Can you post an image of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your design, but you should always start with something like this...

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
```

You may also need to add some inline styles like the following style rules to get rid of some other spacing, but this will effect the text inside the table.

```
style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0;"
```

Comment: Good idea to try inline but doesnt work either. Outlook html display doenst seem to work with cellspacing inline either. I really dont care much for Microsoft. Thx though.